# New paragraph style

Tags: paragraphs

I want to create a few new paragraph styles for a user manual I am writing. The trick part is I want to add an Icon to the beging of the line.
I want to create three styles;

- Danger
- Warning
- Important

each is differnt in terms of color and have different icons. I want it to be more like a textbox with a boarder around it. keeping in mind that each instance will be no more than 2 lines at very most. e.g.

> [image]
>   **Warning;** Risk of Electric Shock

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13532/how-to-insert-code-and-graphic-in-textbox (possible duplicate?)

Comment: the `bclogo` package should do this; it even includes the relevant icons

Comment: I support @prettygully's comment, the `bclogo` package is pretty good at doing this.

Comment: Thanks, The bclogo package seems to be exactly what i want. only problem is i am having a bit of trouble understanding the french documentation. dose anyone know how to add a new icon?

Answer (score 2):

You can define new icons for bclogo just following the pattern shown on page 18 of the documentation:

```
\newcommand{\warninglogo}{\includegraphics[width=\logowidth]{warning.png}}
```

assuming that your logo is in `warning.png`; `\logowidth` is a length parameter that defaults to 17pt and can be changed by `\setlength{\logowidth}{<length>}`.

You can then use

```
\begin{bclogo}[<other settings>,logo=\warninglogo]{Title}
text
\end{bclogo}
```